# case_when output conditioned by two character columns

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I am currently trying to populate a column based on two character columns.

Sample Code:

```
A <- structure(list(Name = c("Piece 1", "Piece 1", "Piece 1","Piece 1"), Size = c("S", 
                                                                        "M", "L", NA_character_), SKU = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,NA_character_
                                                                        )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is a preview of my current approach, not really sure why it is not responding to this condition. If the Name == "X" and the Size == "Y" ~ "Custom Field":

```
A <- A %>%
  mutate(Size = replace_na(Size, "OS")) %>%
  mutate(SKU = case_when(
    SKU == (Name == "Piece1" & 
                    Size == "S") ~ "PS",
    SKU == (Name == "Piece1" & 
                    Size == "M") ~ "PM",
    SKU == (Name == "Piece1" & 
                    Size == "L") ~ "PL",
    SKU == (Name == "Piece1" & 
                    Size == "OS") ~ "POS",
    TRUE ~ as.character(SKU)))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SKU ==` seems unnecessary in `case_when`. Also text to be matched should be exact. You are comparing with `Name == "Piece1"` but in data you have `"Piece 1"` (with a space).

```
library(dplyr)

A %>%
  mutate(SKU = case_when(
    Name == "Piece 1" & Size == "S" ~ "PS",
    Name == "Piece 1" & Size == "M" ~ "PM",
    Name == "Piece 1" & Size == "L" ~ "PL",
    TRUE ~ as.character(SKU)))

#     Name Size SKU
#1 Piece 1    S  PS
#2 Piece 1    M  PM
#3 Piece 1    L  PL
```

---

For the updated data to handle `NA` values -

```
A %>%
  mutate(SKU = replace(Size, is.na(Size), 'OS'),
         #tidyr::replace_na also works
         #SKU = tidyr::replace_na(Size, 'OS'),
         SKU = case_when(
           Name == "Piece 1" & Size == "S" ~ "PS",
           Name == "Piece 1" & Size == "M" ~ "PM",
           Name == "Piece 1" & Size == "L" ~ "PL",
           TRUE ~ as.character(SKU)))

#     Name Size SKU
#1 Piece 1    S  PS
#2 Piece 1    M  PM
#3 Piece 1    L  PL
#4 Piece 1 <NA>  OS
```

Comment: The Piece1 was an error creating the dput() example, the fix solution was the extra (SKU ==) /facepalm Thanks for that!

Comment: I deleted my previous post by accident, I tried this but it doesn't add the NA values. mutate(Size = case_when(is.na(Size) ~ "OS", TRUE ~ as.character(Size))) Assuming there is a 4th row with Piece 1, NA and I want SKU to be OS

Comment: Ill update it in a sec, I think I need to use replace_na since I am trying to add a value to Size but mutate(size = replace_na(size, "OS")) it is not working

Comment: I just updated the code so its a bit more clear

Comment: Is it possible to pass it as a separate argument instead of nested in the case_when?

Comment: @k3r0 I don't know why it doesn't work for you. For me `case_when`, `replace_na` and `replace` all work. I have also updated the answer.

Comment: I think I need to comeback at it later with a fresh mind, thanks for the help!